# When rotating a character, it rotates a certain amount, and then goes back

Tags: javascript, canvas, rotation

I'm just starting to throw together a simple game where your a dot that need food, or else you die. Simple, it's just a fun thing to do.

I'm trying a different method than what I normally do, where the character rotates and then moves.

When the character rotates, it goes a certain amount, and then rotates in the other direction a certain amount. Then it repeats. How do I make it just rotate one direction, rather than alternating(and sort of just going in the same general direction the whole time).

Rotate script:

```
self.rotationy = 0;
self.rotationx = 0;
self.turnLeft = function() {
    self.rotationy -= 0.1;
};
self.turnRight = function() {
    self.rotationy += 0.1;
};
self.move = function() {
    var posX = Math.sin(self.rotationy);
    var posZ = Math.cos(self.rotationy);
    self.locationx += posX + 3;
    self.locationy += posZ + 3;
};
```

If it's important, here's the update script:

```
self.update = function() {
    self.hunger -= 0.003;
    self.updateColour();
    if (self.hunger <= 0) {
        self.die();
    } else if (self.hunger >= 1) {
        self.die();
    }
    if (self.locationx <= 20) {
        self.locationx = canvas.width - 21;
    } else if (self.locationx >= canvas.width - 20) {
        self.locationx = 21;
    } else if (self.locationy <= 20) {
        self.locationy = canvas.height - 21;
    } else if (self.locationy >= canvas.height) {
        self.locationy = 21;
    }
    drawCircle(ctx, self.locationx, self.locationy, 20, self.colour);
};
self.die = function() {

};
    setInterval(self.update, 50);
};
```

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hzhubf8o/

Also note that I haven't created a function to clear the path that's taken.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't reproduce your "alternating" problem, but the "same general direction" is because of the `+ 3` you have there - it will always go in the positive direction along X and Y.

Comment: Oh. Thanks! That did it. But it goes slowly now, how do I speed it up?

Comment: You could try `*` for a start...

Comment: I tried that before and it didn't work. There was probably something that I had differently before, though. Thanks again XD.

Comment: I'm tempted to close this as "a simple typographical error" now, as this seems more than trivial to me... but then again, I'm a math person, and this question is probably actually gonna help some people...

Comment: Yeah, it's probably safe to close. Looking back on it, it's pretty obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Siguza, I have the answer(posting it here in case anyone had a similar problem)

I was adding +3, which caused the character to go along the positive. It was supposed to make him go faster, which instead was supposed to be * 3(also suggested by him).

```
self.locationx += posX + 3;
self.locationy += posZ + 3;
```

Changes to:

```
self.locationx += posX * 3;
self.locationy += posZ * 3;
```